# HTTP Basic authentication using CEFSharp

Tags: c#, windows, cefsharp

The task of the program is such that when the application is opened, an automatic login to the site occurs, which requests HTTP authentication, provided that the login, password and URL are entered in advance.

I tried to embed login and password in the address bar using this method:

```
if (auth.URL.Contains(@"http://") || auth.URL.Contains(@"http:\\"))
{
    auth.URL = $"http://{auth.Login}:{auth.Password}@{auth.URL.Remove(0, 7)}/";
}
else if (auth.URL.Contains(@"https://") || auth.URL.Contains(@"https:\\"))
{
    auth.URL = $"https://{auth.Login}:{auth.Password}@{auth.URL.Remove(0, 8)}/";
}
else
{
    auth.URL = $"http://{auth.Login}:{auth.Password}@{auth.URL}/";
}
```

But I noticed that if I paste the test login "ENTERPRISE\A.Example" and the password "#Mdm256$" into the address bar, the site cannot open normally. I figured out it was because of the \ and # signs. I also tried to write a custom `MyRequestHandler` class with the `GetAuthCredentials()` method:

```
protected override bool GetAuthCredentials(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, bool isProxy, string host, int port, string realm, string scheme, IAuthCallback callback)
{
    callback.Continue(username, password);
    return true;
}
```

But it is not called or used in the code and there was no information anywhere on how to call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign your custom `RequestHandler` instance to the `ChromiumWebBrowser.RequestHandler` property as shown below:

```cs
browser.RequestHandler = new CustomRequestHandler();

public class CustomRequestHandler : CefSharp.Handler.RequestHandler
{
    protected override bool GetAuthCredentials(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, bool isProxy, string host, int port, string realm, string scheme, IAuthCallback callback)
    {
        //Cast IWebBrowser to ChormiumWebBrowser if you need to access the UI control
        //You can Invoke onto the UI Thread if you need to show a dialog
        var b = (ChromiumWebBrowser)chromiumWebBrowser;

        if(!isProxy)
        {
            using (callback)
            {
                callback.Continue(username: "user", password: "pass");
            }

            return true;
        }

        //Return false to cancel the request
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for solving the problem, you made me think that I was stupid and declared `CustomRequestHandler` after loading the site, and not before.